# Airflow Scheduling by weekly/monthly how to pick the start date when I want the end date as processing date

Tags: airflow, airflow-taskflow

My requirements is to schedule the Airflow Dag weekly/monthly. I have gone through the concepts of airflow like, it will execute the dag once the interval is completed, date_interval_end=date_interval_start+ interval.

In my case I am getting files every weekly on monday at 6:00 am CST in S3 Bucket, I want to process them at 6:30am CST.

eg: I am getting files on 2023-11-13, so I have set start_date as 2023-11-6 and cron expression in scheduler as '30 6 * * 1'.
date_interval_start = 2023-11-06 06:30:00
date_interval_end = 2023-11-13 06:30:00.

Appreciate you help, thanks

The DAG is getting triggered but its logical_date is set to 2023-11-06 and its processing last week files instead of the 2023-11-13 files. Overall DAG is processing 1 week old files.

In the code I am making use of ds macro to pick the latest files. I can't set ds to date_interval_end macro as by doing this, the DAG can't be executed for custom date incase of delay in the files.

Comment: If it covers interval 2023-11-06 06:30 to 2023-11-13 06:30 then files arriving at 2023-11-13 06:00 *should* be caught, no? At least if you use proper conditions - show the full code of your DAG.

Comment: Hi @kombajn, Thank you for the comment. For interval 2023-11-06 to 2023-11-13 the ds value will be set to interval start date ie 2023-11-06. I am using ds value to compare the S3 file upload date to pick the files. Thank you

Comment: `ds` is a date. Why not using `data_interval_start/end`? (->[templates reference](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html))

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy,
Thank you for the reply.
But I can't make use of data_interval_start/end here. Because this approach works well incase of scheduled only, but if we want to do manual load for any specific date then for every run dt is set to data_interval_start value.
I am trying solve this by making use of run_type of job. If its scheduled/manual based on it I am trying to set the dt value in the code. I am testing I will post the answer if it works.
Thank you.